# Spring mongodb Find document if a single field matches in a list within a document

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I have some data stored as

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("abc"),
    "_class" : "com.xxx.Team",
    "name" : "Team 1",
    "members" : [ 
        {"userId" : 1, "email" : "a@x.com" },
        {"userId" : 2, "email" : "b@x.com" },
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("xyz"),
    "_class" : "com.xxx.Team",
    "name" : "Team 2",
    "members" : [ 
        {"userId" : 2, "email" : "b@x.com" },
        {"userId" : 3, "email" : "c@x.com" }
    ]
}
```

I have 2 POJO classes `Team` (mapped to entire document),`TeamMember` (mapped to `members` inside a document).

Now I want to find to which team a specific user belongs to. For example if I search for `a@x.com` it should return me the document for **Team 1**. Similarly searching for `b@x.com` should return both of them as its in both the documents.

As I am very new to spring, not able to find out how to solve this.

Note: I am using MongoTemplate

Comment: are you using spring data Repository or MongoTemplate to query your database ? Update your question with your pojo classes  (Team and TeamMember)

Comment: @pvpkiran I am using MongoTemplate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code with the `MongoTemplate`

```
Query findQuery = new Query();
Criteria findCriteria =  Criteria.where("members.email").is("b@x.com");
findQuery.addCriteria(findCriteria);
List<Team> teams = mongoTemplate.find(findQuery, Team.class);
```

Answer (score 1):

somthing like this will do

```
 final QueryBuilder queryBuilder = QueryBuilder.start();
 //queryBuilder.and("members.email").is("a@x.com") This will work as well. try it out.
  queryBuilder.and("members.email").in(Arrays.asList("a@x.com"))

 final BasicDBObject projection = new BasicDBObject();
        projection.put("fieldRequired", 1);


 try (final DBCursor cursor = mongoTemplate.getCollection(collectionName).find(queryBuilder.get(), projection)
            .batchSize(this.readBatchSize)) {
            while (cursor.hasNext()) {
                DBObject next = cursor.next();
                ........
                // read the fields using next.get("field")
                .........
            }
        }
```

batchsize and projection is not mandatory. Use projection if you don't want to fetch the whole document. You can specify which field in the document you want to fetch in the result.